# Find and replace variable number of items in string using regex

Tags: regex, string, notepad++

I have several strings that looks like this:

```
sum({foo, c[0663, 0667, 0673, 0677, 0693, 0697, 0703, 0707]})
sum({foo, c[0663, 0667, 0673, 0677, 0693]})
sum({foo, c[0697, 0703, 0707]})
sum({foo, c[0693, 0697, 0703, 0707]})
```

I can find all of them, using this regex:

```
sum\(\{foo, c\[(?:(\d{4})(, )?)+\]\}\)
```

The problem appears when I need to replace the lines, which contain a variable occurrences of 4 digits, separated by a comma and a space.

So the output of the first line should look like this:

```
[1234] 0663 + [1234] 0667 + [1234] 0673 + [1234] 0677 + [1234] 0693 + [1234] 0697 + [1234] 0703 + [1234] 0707
```

Of the second line:

```
[1234] 0663 + [1234] 0667 + [1234] 0673 + [1234] 0677 + [1234] 0693
```

And so on.

So basically, all occurrences of the four digit characters, must be replaced by:

```
[1234] xxxx
```

("[1234]" is a constant string) (x represents a digit)

and the

```
,
```

(comma space)

must be replaced by

```
+
```

(plus sign)

Therefore, it must not have the + sign neither at the beginning nor the end of the line, hence why, the four digits are treated separately from the ", " (comma space).

Normally, I would do the replacement pattern like:

```
[1234] \1
```

But this will put [1234] and the last saved pattern, so in the case of the first line, it would be replaced into:

```
[1234] 0707
```

Also, the ", " (comma space) part must always be replaced into plus sign.

Comment: Maybe show the output you are getting, and where the problem is exactly - it doesn't appear that there is a problem otherwise.

Comment: I couldn't find a viable solution for the output. I do not know how to specify that in the search string, parts occurred various times, and were saved various times.

Comment: So is the issue that you are not getting all of the groups of digits, or rather replacing the `,`?

Comment: Both. I am not getting all of the groups of digits, this is more important. The replacement of the comma I could do in a second replacement, and not have to use regex at all. So if the first problem is solved, it would be great!

Comment: I also checked here, but I could not adapt it to my problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915013/replacing-variable-numbers-of-items-regex

Comment: yes, this is a constant, that will be put before each saved group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `\G` based regex with a conditional replacement pattern:

*Find What*: `(?:\G,\h*|^sum\(\{foo,\h*c\[)(\d{4})(\]\}\))?`
*Replace With*: `(?{2}[1234] $1:[1234] $1 + )`

*Note*: If the `]})` must appear at the end of the line, add `$` - `(\]\}\)$)?`

[image]

**Details**:

- `(?:\G,\h*|^sum\(\{foo,\h*c\[)` - either `sum({foo, c[` like pattern at the start of a string/line (see `^sum\(\{foo,\h*c\[`) or the end of the preceding successful match with a `,` and 0+ horizontal whitespaces (see `\G,\h*`)
- `(\d{4})` - Group 4: exactly four digits
- `(\]\}\))?` - an optional Group 2: a sequence of `]})`, one or zero times

The replacement pattern:

- `(?{2}` - (*conditional replacement pattern start*) If Group 2 matched:

  - `[1234] $1` - literal `[1234]`  substring and the Group 1 value
  - `:` - else
  - `[1234] $1 +`  - literal `[1234]`  substring, the Group 1 value and a  `+`  literal char sequence
- `)` - end of the conditional replacement.

Comment: I see what you did there... I understand it! Thank you very much, sir!